# Need a hint for an expected value problem

Tags: probability, expectation

You are allowed to write positive integers from 1 to 100 on 100 cards, you the show the 100 cards to a friend who will pick a number. You then shuffle the deck and flip off the top card. If the top card was the number your friend selected you pay him that number. Assuming your friend picks the number to maximize his expected value what numbers do you place on each of the 100 cards to minimize his expected value

My strategy was to start from the highest number we can place in the deck and go down. For example we can't place a hundred in the deck because this would give an expected value of 1 if the friend picked 100, but this isn't giving me much progress. Any suggestions are appreciated

Comment: _"You then shuffle the deck and flip off the top card."_ This shuffle is an honest, random shuffle?

Comment: Yeah the idea is that the friend knows the distribution of the deck so will pick the number that gives him the highest EV

Answer (score 3):

Assuming there are $k$ copies of a card with value $n$ in the deck, the expected value of  picking that card is $\frac{kn}{100}$.

Suppose there is some optimal expected value $v$. Then we know that $\frac{kn}{100} \leq v$. But we can rearrange that to $k \leq \frac{100v}{n}$.

So if we assume $v = \frac12$ we find that for $n = 1$ we can use up to $k = 50$ cards. And continuing we find that we use $50, 25, 16, 9$ cards of respectively $1, 2, 3, 4$ by choosing the highest value of $k$ possible for each $n$, and this reaches $100$ cards.

If we assume $v$ small enough we won't be able to reach $100$ cards because the limits on $k$ become too tight. So there must be some smallest $v$ that's feasible.

Does this help? Spoiler for $v$:

> $v$ = 0.28 is optimal.

Comment: Hmm interesting how did you compute the optimal value. I just started bashing some numbers using x + x/2 + x/3 + ... where x was the number of ones(and he EV). Got it down to 0.33 but I didn't know how to optimize it

Comment: @GTOgod I wrote a little program. Essentially you're looking for the first term in [this sequence](http://oeis.org/A006218) that's bigger than or equal to $100$.

Comment: So I got the minimum of 28 after some number bashing. Question: Is it always the case that the number of ones equals the expected value in the minimum EV setup

Comment: @GTOgod No, use the formula $k \leq \frac{100v}{n}$ to answer that question. Hint: $100$ is confusing you here, what would happen if the number of cards was some non-nice number like $172$?

Answer (score 3):

HINT

If you write down all the numbers $1$ through $100$, then your friend will of course pick $100$ and has an expected payoff of $1$.

Can you do better? Sure, don't include $100$ ... but that means you have to have some number twice. No problem, just have two $1$'s ... your friend has twice the chance of winning when picking $1$, but since the payout is so low, that gives an expected payoff of $0.02$, and so your friend is far better off picking $99$ ... which has an expected payoff of $0.99$. Of course, even better would be to have three $1$'s and have $98$ be the highest ... but if you go all the way and get just $100$ $1$'s, then your friend will pick $1$, and is certain to win $1$.  So, I think you now see where this is going: Try to strike a balance between avoiding using high numbers, and how many multiples of the low numbers you are using.

In fact, here is what you need to do: have a whole bunch of $1$'s ... and a good bunch of $2$'s, a decent amount of $3$'s, etc. Where of course  you try to make the expected payoff roughly the same for each number.

Comment: Right this is what I was thinking, but I'm having trouble constructing a distribution and actually verifying that it is the lowest. My first though was to do a geometric sum where I included 50 ones 25 twos 12.5 fours etc but obviously I can't use fractions. My second thought was to start at 50 and reconstruct the smaller numbers from there

Comment: Rethinking it I think I should try x + x/2 + x/3 + ... = 100 where x is the number of ones. Does this sound like a good idea

Comment: @GTOgod with 50 1's you can also have 16 3's, so you're already up to 50+25+16+12>100.

Comment: @GTOgod Yes, except that you  don't know what the last term corresponding to highest number is.

Comment: @GTOgod So maybe it's a metter of trial and error after all. E.g start with 40: 40,20,13,10,8,6,5 ... >100 ... so we can start lower yet: 30,15,10,7,6,5,4,3,3,3,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1ooh, still works! But we went up to 18 .. so I'm guessing high 20's ....

Comment: Yeah I am just bashing through numbers in the low 30s. One of the answerers somehow came to an optimum of 0.28

Comment: Well: 28,14,9,7,5,4,4,3,3,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1 ... that's 100 with the highest number 27. Yep, seems right! 28 it is.

Comment: Yeah the only remaining question I have is why the setup floor(x)+ floor(x/2) + floor(x/3) + ... actually leads to the minimum EV. It made sense when I constructed it in my head, but I can't really formalize the logic

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69362/discussion-between-bram28-and-gtogod).

Comment: @GTOgod Well, remember your friend will always pick the number with the best expected payoff, and we just verified that with $28$ $1$'s you can keep the payoff for any number to a maximum of $0.28$, so if we increase the number of $1$'s, your friend will pick the $1$s for a payoff that's better than $0.28$ while if we decrease the number of $1$s we need an extra number elsewhere, but we maximized those already so you will go above $0.28$ for that number as well.

Answer (score 0):

First, you must have at least one $1$ in your deck, because if you didn’t, you could subtract $1$ from each card to get a deck that has lower expected values for each possible value. In a similar fashion, you should be able to convince yourself that you must use the first $k$ integers, for some $k\leq 100$.

Now, notice that if your friend picks the number $\ell$ and there are $c_{\ell}$instances of  $\ell$ in the deck, the expected value is $(c_\ell/100)\ell$. so if there are $c_1$ $1$’s, $c_2$ $2$’s, all the way up to $c_k$ $k$’s, you essentially want to make sure that $(c_i/100)i$ is about the same for any $i$.

Thus informally we want $c_1\approx 2c_2\approx...\approx kc_k$. If $c_1+c_2+\dots+c_k=100$, can you figure out good choices for the $c_i$’s?